# Why isn't my code posting data from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So in my `login` page form members, I'm trying to dynamically pull data from the SQL database depending on the user who logged in. I determine which user is logged in by using session variables. But, the following code to retrieve name from database comes out blank, could someone explain why?

```
<tr>
                <td>Name</td>
              <td>
              <?php
                $offset = $argv[0];
                $connect = mysqli_connect("****.****", "*****", "******", "****");
                $output = '';
                if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
                  $username = $_SESSION["username"];
                }
                else {
                  $username = $_SESSION["regusername"];
                }
                $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE username = $username $offset";
                $output = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                echo $output;
              ?>
           </td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: You need quotes around `$username` in the query. But you should use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: You also need to call a `mysqli_fetch_XXX()` function to fetch the result row. See the proper way to do queries in any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a prepared statement first and foremost like this:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("****.****", "*****", "******", "****");

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

    if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
      $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    }
    else {
      $username = $_SESSION["regusername"];
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM `users` WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($output);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $output;
    }//end while
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to put in the question mark for the offset

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't a LIMIT required for OFFSET to work?

Comment: Jeez, good morning. I really need another cup of coffee, I actually deleted the variable setting the offset but not in the bind param...

Comment: Is there something I need to change in your code for it to work? Cause it's not right now.

Comment: Its giving me a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Could you try the updated code, I have included some error reporting.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks.